# What is Disgorging or Dégorgement?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, sediment

What is Disgorging and how is it performed on fizzy wine?

I have heard it is a part of the process to make champagne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disgorging](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptEzoPcehC4) is a way to remove sediment from fizzy wines.

This is the process of storing bottles upsidedown and rotating over weeks for sediment to rest in the lid. When very cold a quick upside down pop of the lid shots out the sediment. You must place your thumb over the opening immediately! to not lose everything! When pressure calms down remove your thumb and top up with more champagne from a donor bottle (wine+sugar) and re-seal the bottles, the fizz will be regained.
To Aid you, you can have the bottles upside down in ice and salt to freeze only the neck, so that slush sediment is forced out a little slower so you loose less wine.